# Want to trigger an edit with an icon on the header of a Boostrap Accordion

Tags: jquery

I have a Bootstrap 3 accordion with a pencil icon on the header. When the corresponding panel is open, I would like to be able to click the pencil icon and trigger an edit. However, as it is now, the click of the icon closes the panel. I tried to override this by raising the z-index on the icon to no avail

HTML

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
    @foreach($topics as $topic)
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" data-target="#{{$topic->slug}}">
                <h4 class="panel-title">{{$topic->topic}} </h4>
                    <span class="pull-right" style="margin-top:-16px;">
                        <i class="btnEdit fa fa-pencil"></i>
                     </span>
             </div>
             <div id="{{$topic->slug}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                 <div class="panel-body">
                     @include("contracts.GTA." . $topic->slug)
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     @endforeach
 </div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.btnEdit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(clicked); //just get something working
});
```

SASS

```
.panel-heading {
    z-index: 1;
}
.panel-heading.collapsed .btnEdit {
    color:#c2c2c2;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.panel-heading .btnEdit {
    color:#900;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.panel-heading:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.panel-heading:hover h4 {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must override the accordion click event, try this:

```
$('#accordion1 .btnEdit')
        .off('click')
    .click(function(){
        //doe something
    });​
```